# Pandas change one columns data if another columns data is in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in a data frame like this:

```
COLUMNS Point,x,y,z,Description,Layer,Date
1,224939.203,1243008.651,1326.774,F,C-GRAD-FILL,09/22/18 07:24:34,
1,225994.242,1243021.426,1301.772,BS,C-GRAD-FILL,09/24/18 08:24:18,
451,225530.332,1243016.186,1316.173,GRD,C-TOE,10/02/18 11:49:13,
452,225522.429,1242996.017,1319.168,GRD,C-TOE KEY,10/02/18 11:49:46,
```

I would like to try to try to check against a list of strings to see if it matches, and then change another columns value.

```
myList = ["BS", "C"]
if df['Description'].isin(myList)) == True:
     df['Layer']="INLIST"
     df['Date']="1/1/2018'
```

Comment: Can please you put the dataFrame in the POST, so to get the  answers, this looks to be more comma separated data seems like csv dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a mask with [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df['Description'].isin(['BS', 'C'])
df.loc[mask, 'Layer'] = 'INLIST'
df.loc[mask, 'Date'] = '1/1/2018'
```

Alternatively, use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = df['Description'].isin(['BS', 'C'])
df['Layer'].mask(mask, 'INLIST', inplace=True)
df['Date'].mask(mask, '1/1/2018', inplace=True)
```

Note you should probably store dates as `datetime` objects, e.g. `pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')`, or convert your series via [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). There's usually no need for a Python-level loop.

Answer (score 1):

Borrow the `mask` from jpp and using list to assign the value

```
df.loc[mask,['Layer','Date']]=['INLIST','1/1/2018']
```

Comment: But there is condition as well if `['BS', 'C']` in  `Description`, so you need to consider that as well.

Comment: @pygo mask from jpp :-)